# Graph containing every trees of size $n$ as subgraphs

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

> What is the minimum number of edges of graph $G$, so that every tree of size $n$ is a subgraph of $G$?

I personally managed to find a lower bound of $c n \log n $ and an upper bound of $C n \log ^2 n$. But what I'm actually trying to ask is not the problem itself, but reference for it. I strongly believe that this problem would had been considered by some mathematicians, but searching gives articles about minimum spanning tree. Where can I find some results for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such kind of graphs are called [universal graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_graph), and Chung and Graham [proved](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~fan/mypaps/fanpap/fc35universal_trees.pdf) that there exists such a graph with $O(n \log n)$ edges.

Answer (score 0):

This is called the Erdős and Sós conjecture on trees. See [here](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~erdosproblems/erdos/newproblems/AllTreesSubgraphs.html). The conjecture was recently proved.

Comment: Do you, by any chance, have a reference to the proof of the conjecture ?

Comment: Thanks for this interesting conjecture. But what I'm asking is the minimum number of edges required for some graph, while the conjecture is asking for all graph.

Comment: @manuellafond It was presented by Szemerédi at the Erdos conference last year.